# How to change the root file on htaccess

Tags: apache

Because of my host system I have different folders for some domains(domain.com, domain2.com, domain3.com)

- DomainFolder
- DomainFolder2
- DomainFolder3

Every domain should point to Domain, but the host told me that they work only in that way for multiple domains and that I should write a .htaccess on Domain1, Domain2, etc to send that domains point to DomainFolder.
How can I make that a htaccess changes the request file from DomainFolder1 to DomainFolder?¿?¿?¿?¿?